# Repeating Fields in Custom List

Tags: 2013, infopath, custom-list, lookup-column, custom-form

During research and testing I came across some issues while trying to create repeating fields.

Intent: Create repeating fields in a custom list form

Problem: In the custom list I can create 5 columns asking for the same information but I don't like this way because my list will grow large with a lot columns.  I can create a InfoPath form but I do not want it in a form library because I don't want to item saved as a form.

Possible solutions: 
Read in posts (that I don't understand) to

> 1. If part of your content is repeating, consider flattening that schema
>      so that it can repeat. For example, you could limit your book request
>      form to no more than ten books per form.
> 2. You can also use multiple
>      lists and link them together using lookup fields and web part
>      connections. This works well for master/detail scenarios where one
>      list tracks all the items and another contains the specific details
>      for each item.

## 2 above sounds good not sure how to do it.

Question:  Is there a way to create repeating fields in a custom list that will save into the list and not a InfoPath form? If using InfoPath will not give me that outcome, how can I do this just using SharePoint form?

Comment: Keep in mind what you ask is Relational Data (and even in a Database requires 2 Tables). SharePoint is not a Relational Database. With the Master/Detail lookup you can replicate simple Relational behavior, but it always requires 2 Lists. Doing what you ask (storing both Master and Detail records in 1 List) can be done, but requires some advanced SharePoint techniques; multiple ContentTypes in one List, rewriting source= parameters and additional CSR (ClientSideRendering) javascript.

Comment: You can also customise a list form using info path

Comment: @HarryB I thought that would be a simple approach using a list from using info path but I don't want a library full of forms.  Or maybe I am doing something wrong.  Can you have any steps on how to create repeating fields in a list form using info path? Also, Repeating Field is not a control available to add to form. thanks

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? I have run into the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint handles the concept of "repeating fields" through the use of "multi-item lookups" - in other words, create a Lookup Field and then check the box to "Allow Multiple Items". This gets your data schema "right".

From here, users can select as many items as necessary from the lookup list to add to the new item in your form - but they cannot create new items on the fly, and they will see ALL the records in the lookup list. You'll need to implement some sort of custom code solution (i.e. JSLink, popup window for entering new items, etc.) to streamline the UI further. There isn't anything OOB. I know my company has a product that provides similar functionality; there may be others as well.